# Java Best practice on subclass and interface

Tags: java, class, inheritance, interface, extends

I have 4 different class named Class A, Class B, Class C and Class P,
Class A, B and C each have a subclass named Class X, Class Y and Class Z

Class X, Y and Z will handle two events from Class P, 
so there are a listener interface named Interface I with method G and H,
X, Y and Z also implements Interface I.

The problem is 70% of event handling logic (method G, H) are the same in X, Y and Z, 
I want to taken them out, but where should I put it into ?

Now I create a new class for the same handling logic and Keep X,Y and Z implements I, call the new class in method G and H, but is there any better way to do this ?

Comment: Which version of Java?  There's a way of doing this cleanly in Java 8 which doesn't exist in earlier versions.

Comment: Should be SE6 / 7, actually I'm developing Android.

Comment: In that case, what you're doing is probably fine.  Keep your new class as the event handler, and give it a reference to something implementing I if it needs it.

Comment: I see, thanks. But what if Java 8 ? interested.

Comment: In Java 8, you can give interface methods default implementations.  I dislike this feature for a few reasons.  It effectively blurs the distinction between an interface and an abstract class, and introduces multiple inheritance to Java, and all its associated problems.  But I think your use case is a reasonable use of it.